# Factoring a multiset into a product of two multisets

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, discrete-mathematics

Given a multiset $S$ of $mn$ numbers, how hard is to find multisets $A$ and $B$, of $m$ and $n$ numbers respectively, such that
$$ S = \{ xy \mid x\in A, y\in B \}~~~~\text{(multiset sense)}, $$
or prove that there are none?

For example, if I give you $S=\{6,8,15,15,20,20\}, m=2,n=3$, you will tell me $A=\{3,4\}$, $B=\{2,5,5\}$.

I used the vague word "numbers" to mean anything you like.  Choose "positive integers", "integers", "real numbers", "elements of my favourite quasigroup" as you please.  Personally I think "real numbers" grabs the essence of the problem, as the subtask of factoring integers is a distraction.  Assume you can do exact arithmetic in constant time per basic operation.

If you are working in a ring, the task looks the same as that of arranging the $mn$ numbers in an $m\times n$ matrix so that the rank is 1.

If your numbers are "positive reals", then you can take logarithms to convert the multiplication into addition, in which case the question is a bit like [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13789/wants-polynomial-time-algorithm-for-decomposing-a-multiset-of-rationals-into-tw).  But I don't care about finding all factorizations, just whether there is none or more than none.

I don't any more have an application for this.  I just thought it might disturb your sleep like it disturbed mine.

Comment: In integer case, this problem is some kind of generalization of the factoring of an integer and I think it is much harder than factorization of a number. Let $S=\{n\}$, where $n$ is the product of two prime numbers $p$ and $q$ and let $m=n=1$. This nice problem can be used to define generalized $RSA$ cryptosystem. Anyway, I want to go to sleep.

Comment: @ShahroozJanbaz This problem only asks whether such sets $A,B$ exist, so for $S=\{n\}$ it's just asking whether $n$ is prime, which is easier than factorization. (I assume you consider only integers above $1$.)

Comment: @Jik : Actually there is always a solution, $A=\{1\}, B=\{n\}$.  I don't know if any larger problem can actually force integer factorisation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the positive integers case and rely on existence of unique prime factorizations and linear order for them.

Let $P$ be the product of all elements of $S$.

Assuming we can find prime factorization of each element of $S$ (and thus $P$), here are some quick tests for the "None" answer:

1. Test whether we can represent $P$ as the product of $m$-th and $n$-th powers. That is, the answer is "None" if for some prime $p\mid P$, we cannot represent $\nu_p(P)$ as a linear combination of $m$ and $n$ with nonnegative integer coefficients.
2. Let $k_p$ be the number of elements of $S$ divisible by $p$. For each prime $p\mid P$, the number $mn-k_p$ must be equal to $x\cdot y$, where $x$ and $y$ would be the number of elements not divisible by $p$ in $A$ and $B$, respectively. That is, $mn-k_p$ must be the product of two numbers below $n$ and $m$, respectively. If not, the answer is "None".

Now, let me describe a simple backtracking algorithm that tries to fill up an empty $m\times n$ table $M$ with the elements of $S$ to turn it into a multiplication table. We assume that the elements of $S$ are sorted in non-decreasing order.

1. We place the first (smallest) element of $S$ to $M_{1,1}$.
2. For each subsequent element $s$ of $S$, we will try to place it to empty cells that are adjacent to the occupied ones (e.g., we can place the second element of $S$ either to $M_{1,2}$ and $M_{2,1}$), subject to the following constraints.
3. Placing an element $s$ to $M_{i,j}$ is allowed only if the following conditions hold:

   **(i)** $s$ must divide
   $$\gcd(M_{i,1},M_{i,2},\dots,M_{i,{j-1}})\cdot \gcd(M_{1,j},M_{2,j},\dots,M_{i-1,j});$$
    and

   **(ii)** if $\gcd(M_{i,1},M_{i,2},\dots,M_{i,{j-1}},s)<\gcd(M_{i,1},M_{i,2},\dots,M_{i,{j-1}})$, then we re-test as in (i) that each $M_{i,k}$ remains allowed at its position with $s$ placed at $M_{i,j}$; and

   **(iii)** similarly we check the inequality $\gcd(M_{1,j},M_{2,j},\dots,M_{i-1,j},s)<\gcd(M_{1,j},M_{2,j},\dots,M_{i-1,j})$ and that all these elements remain allowed at their positions.
4. If conditions (i)-(iii) hold, we place $s$ to $M_{i,j}$ and iterate to step 2. If not, we go to the next potential placement for $s$. If all placements are exhausted, we return to the previous element and try to find it a new placement, etc. If this way we ever return to the first element of $S$, the answer is "None".

When the whole table is filled, we try to recover the elements of $A$ and $B$ from linear algebra on the prime exponents for each prime $p\mid P$ (perhaps, something can be done here even if we cannot factor $P$). Notice that $\gcd$'s of rows and columns give multiples of the corresponding elements of $A$ and $B$ (if they exist). If the product of $\gcd$ of $i$-th row and $\gcd$ of $j$-th column give $M_{i,j}$, then these $\gcd$'s are the elements of $A$ and $B$.